# Join two Data Frames in Pandas based on third data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have 3 pandas df with **different dimensions**.
The first frame is as follows-

```
df1.head(4)

col1   col2   col3
  a      b     c
  d      e     f
  g      h     i
  j      k     l
```

The second frame is as follows-

```
df2.head(4)

col4   col5   col6
  m      n      o
  p      q      r
  s      t      u
  v      w      x
```

The third data frame has combinations of `col3` of `df1` and `col6` of `df2`. It looks like

```
df3.head(3)

col3    col6
  c       r
  i       u
  f       x
```

Now I want to combine all three data frames based on the combinations in `df3` columns `col3` and `col6`. The resultant df should look like-

```
final_df.head(3)

col1    col2    col4    col5    col2    col6
  a      b       p        q       c       r
  g      h       s        t       i       u
  d      e       v        w       f       x
```

I have tried the following code

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df3, on='col3')
final_df = pd.merge(df4, df2, on='col6')
```

but got the memory error as

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.79 GiB for an array with shape (2, 120193432) and data type int64
```

Is there any other effecient way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The above works fine without a memory error in my side. I am running an 8Gig Ram Computer with 32bit python.

- Give More space to your Computer
- Check and stop apps with high Memory(Ram) usage (mostly chrome tabs)
- Limit data rows if the above dataframes is not what you working with

Comment: I am running on 8 gigs with i5 8 gen, Mint 64 bit. Still, this is not working. I have more than 50k rows in one data frame.